# how to make an image visible in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie to Rails. In html if we want make an image visible we write it as 
`<img src="xyz.jpg"/>`.In this way I want to know how to make that kind of stuff in Rails.How to make an image src in Rails to make it visible.

Answer (score 1):

With the `image_tag` method.

In your case it would be:

```
image_tag("xyz.jpg")
```

This will output as:

```
 <img src="/images/xyz.jpg" />
```

Which assumes that the path is `images/xyz.jpg`

[See here for more details.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean an image tag?

```
image_tag("icon.png")
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag

Comment: ya thanks I got the answer its <%=  image_tag( 'logo.png') %>

Answer (score 1):

In your ERB it will look like this:
`<%= image_tag 'xyz.jpg' %>`